# Difference between averages

Tags: statistics

This is probably very simple, but I need some help.

I have two averages with associated standard deviation ($6 \pm 0.1$ and $8\pm 0.11$). Is it right to say that the difference between these two averages is $2$?

Thanks!

Comment: What are trying to say in your analysis of data?  The population with avg=6  is not the same as the one with avg=8?

Comment: In the absence of context, I cannot be absolutely sure, but almost certainly it is OK. But note that we cannot do the same to the standard deviations. A reasonable estimate for the standard deviation of the difference would be $\sqrt{(0.1)^2+(0.11)^2}$,

Comment: Hi Jim. Yes, these are two different datasets (pH measures). I´m not interested in analysis of variance. I just want to say that dataset number 1 had a reduction of 2 pH units in relation to dataset 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement that the difference of the averages is $2$ is true.  The averages are numbers and you can subtract them.  As they are pH measurements, you could also subtract the hydrogen concentrations and get $10^{-6}-10^{-8}=9.9\cdot10^{-7}$.  Which is more useful is not a mathematical question.

As others have commented, if you want to talk about how close the difference is to $2$ you need to think about variances and the distributions hidden in the $\pm0.1$ which may not be normal.

Comment: Thanks to all for the excellent answers! That really help me!